# Proving that the series $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k \ln k}$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, divergent-series

I don't know how to show this. The terms go to zero, and I can't really show that the terms dominate $\frac{1}{k}$ (a series with these terms diverges). Any other ideas?

Comment: Hint: the derivative of $\ln(\ln x))$ is $\frac1{x\ln x}$.

Comment: Have you heard of D'Alembert Ratio tests and Raabe's test?

Answer (score 3):

Let $k\geq 2$ and let $x \in [k,k+1[$. Since $\displaystyle x \rightarrow \frac{1}{x\ln x}$ is a decreasing function, you may write
$$
\frac{1}{x\ln x} \leq \frac{1}{k\ln k}, 
$$ integrating
$$
\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{x\ln x}dx \leq \int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{k\ln k} dx=\frac{1}{k\ln k}
$$
then summing from $k=2$ to $N-1\geq2$, you get
$$
\int_2^N \frac{1}{x\ln x} dx \leq \sum_{k=2}^{N}\frac{1}{k\ln k} 
$$
thus
$$
\int_2^N \frac{1}{x\ln x} dx =\int_2^N \frac{(\ln x)'}{(\ln x)} dx  = \log(\log(N))-\log( \log 2)\leq \sum_{k=2}^{N}\frac{1}{k\ln k} 
$$ and letting $N$ tend to $+\infty$ gives the divergence of the series.

Answer (score 3):

If you refer Walter Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis, there is a theorem:

If $ x_i $ is a non-negative monotone non-increasing sequence, then

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k \mbox{ converges} \iff \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^kx_{2^k} \mbox{ converges}$$

Comment: This theorem has a name: Cauchy's Condensation Test

Comment: Thanks. I forgot the name.

Answer (score 1):

Compare to the integral $\int \frac{dx}{x \log x}$ because the summand is a montone decreasing function. What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Bertrand series](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html).

Bertrand series are of the kind $\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\dfrac{1}{n^\alpha\ln(n)^\beta}$.

If $\alpha=1$ and $\beta\leq1$ then the series diverges.

Comment: it should start from k=2

Comment: @Mosk Removing/adding a __finite__ number of terms doesn't change whether the series is convergent or divergent :)

Comment: but the denominator is zero in this way!

Comment: @Mosk Oh haha :) thanks I hadn't seen that