# The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following series converges or diverges? $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})}$$
**Myattemp:**

let $a_n=(\frac{1}{n})$ and $b_n=(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}})$, It is enough to apply [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test.)

It follows that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})}$$ is convergent.

Comment: It is divergent. Check again if you applied the test correctly.

Comment: [$H_n=1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n\sim\log n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) hence your series is divergent. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940035/proving-that-the-series-sum-k-2-infty-frac1k-ln-k-diverges/940040#940040

Comment: Anne Bauval, Thanks for your precious comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series diverges. By partial summation, you can establish
$$\sum_{k\le n} \frac1k = \log n + O(1)$$
i.e., for some $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ and $C_0 > 0$, we have $\sum_{k\le n} \frac1 k \le \log n + C_0$ for every $n\ge n_0$. Next, you can find a constant $C_1 > 0$, and $n_1 \in \Bbb N$ such that $\log n + C_0 \le C_1 \log n$ for every $n \ge n_1$. Choose $m = \max\{n_0, n_1\}$. Thus, $\sum_{k\le n} \frac 1 k \le C_1 \log n$ for all $n\ge m$.

Finally,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})} \ge \sum_{n=m}^\infty\frac{1}{n(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})} \ge \frac{1}{C_1} \sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log n} = \infty$$
as the series $\sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log n}$ [diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574503/infinite-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac1n-log-n) by the Cauchy condensation test, for example.

Comment: This answer doesn't address why Dirichlet's Test doesn't work here

Comment: Sure, just pointing out facts in the comments

Comment: stoic-santiago,Thanks  a lot for your good answer

Answer (score 1):

In Dirichlet's Test, $b_n$ must be bounded by a constant. But, since in your case, $b_n = H_n$, the $n$-th harmonic number, and the fact that $H_n \to \infty$ means the conditions of Dirichlet's test do not apply here.

In fact, the sum is divergent. Can you use what you know about $H_n$ to prove the sum is divergent?

Hint: $\text{D}{(\log(\log(n)))} = 1/(n\log n)$

Comment: Snared, Thanks for your precious answer